# error: cannot find symbol method GetApplicationContext()

Tags: android, cannot-find-symbol

I had this error: "error: cannot find symbol method GetApplicationContext()" when I'm creating Fragments for Android app.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void simple(View v){

        Intent intent = new Intent(intent.GetApplicationContext(), SimpleFragmentActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
intent.GetApplicationContext()
```

`getApplicationContext` is not a method of the Intent class but of context.

Change

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(intent.GetApplicationContext(), SimpleFragmentActivity.class);
```

with

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SimpleFragmentActivity.class);
```

or simply

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SimpleFragmentActivity.class);
```

where `this` refers to this object, the Activity, that extends `ContextWrapper`